# Is there an easy way to get sublime text 3 to transpile Typescript?

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

node and tsc installed and working.
I'm using the SublimeOnSaveBuild package with sublime text 3, hoping to make it compile Typescript files into javascript.
the best i was able to achieve is that on save it opens the build params input line, then i hit enter and it does the work. but it's annoying. i want just to save and have the js file ready, like in vs or other tools.
is there a way to avoid this parameters window? there are no params in this case anyways.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`TypeScript`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) plugin? It includes a build system.

Comment: it is installed, and basically working. i just want to make the process faster and more efficient. i don't want to see the param window each time i save a file... thanks.